# Get all entries from std::map that hold come condition?

Tags: c++

in `C#` , I can do:

```
someCollection.Where(element => // apply some condition on element)
```

is there an equivalent in C++?

Specifically, I have a map defined as :

```
std::map<int, std::set<int>> myMap;
```

I want to extract all the entries (not just keys, I need both the keys and the values) such that:

```
// Pseudo
auto entries = myMap.Where(element => element.second.size() == 3);
```

Does this functionality exist in `std`?

Comment: Have a look at [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class R,class Test
  class T=std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<R&>()))>>
auto where(R&& r, Test&& test)
-> std::vector<T>
{
  std::vector<T> ret;
  for(auto&& x:r)
    if(test(x))
      ret.emplace_back(x);
  return ret;
}
```

is a drop in replacement.

It uses C++11.  You pass it a container or range, and a lambda test function.

The calculation of `T` is a bit strange (it calculates at compile time the type of the container/range passed in there, and supports flat C-style arrays).

`std::begin(r)` is a begin iterator into the range `r`.  We dereference it, get that type, then "decay" that (probably reference) type into something suitable for storage.

Use:

```
std::map<std::string, int> bob;

// ...

auto v = where(bob, [&](auto&& x){
  x.first == "hello"; // key is hello
});
```

uses C++14, for the `auto&&` part.  In C++11 we get

```
auto v = where(bob, [&](std::pair<const std::string, int>const &x){
  x.first == "hello"; // key is hello
});
```

which is a bit of a mouthful.

Comment: OP probably needs to know about lambdas too. And why not `std::copy_if`? Since he wants an idiomatic standard C++ solution

Comment: @lightness Because `for(:)` loops are as brief, easier to read, newer, and just as idiomatic.

Comment: ... And iterator based algorithms are annoying.

Comment: missing `,` after `class Test`. and `r` should be `std::declval<R>()` in default `T` declaration.

Comment: @jarod I use `r` in an lvakue context for `begin`, not perfect forwarded.

Comment: @Yakk: I just mean that provided code has typo which doesn't compile : [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e91d3e8bba8847d9), as `r` is not (yet) declared for `T`